# Reading POST data while uploading

Tags: python, apache, post, cgi

I'm about to finish a jquery plugin that should provide a progress-bar for file uploading using ajax and a python CGI script.

My plugin is inspired after [this piece of software](http://development.mumboe.com/?p=11).

The idea is reading(with python CGI script) raw post data on the server while the browser is uploading, parse it, write file (in chunks) to disk and at the same time using ajax to ask the server about the currently written file size.

The plugin works on my server and on some other web hosting servers. But on Mochahost (using apache) it does not work properly. What that server does is that it calls my python CGI script after all upload is completely done, and not while the file is uploading (as expected). I verified the moment of calling by adding the very beginning of python script command to write a test file. That command should fire when python is called and does not involve reading `sys.stdin`.

Even on that server python CGI script works (almost) as intended. It reads `sys.stdin` in chunks, parses it and writes the file on disk. The problem is timing. The server does not provide python with input stream in real-time, but, after all, post from the browser was received, it calls python and populate `sys.stdin` with raw posted data that is already saved somewhere.

I don't know if it is relevant but I've noticed that their apache version is 2.0.x and `SERVER_PROTOCOL` is `HTTP/1.0`. On other web hosting servers `SERVER_PROTOCOL` is `HTTP/1.1`.

Can anybody say what things could make a server or specifically an apache server to call a CGI script after uploading is finished and not when the browser asked for it?

Comment: I'm slightly unknowledgeable about CGI, seeing as it is stoneage technology I haven't used for almost 10 years, but.... Isn't that how CGI works? Like, per definition?

Comment: Don't touch formatting of the post, coolboy, it's been fixed. Leave it that way.

Comment: While on most server configurations python as cgi can intercept raw post data in real time, i think that this is how a cgi script has to work as default. Even more if used as mod_python or other mods it will not have access to raw post data. Isn't it? And this is not the first cgi script trying to intercept input stream in real time. But what makes my troubles is somehow related to Apache behaviour(i think).

Comment: BTW,  even cgi is a stoneage technology what other possibility is to make a smart file uploader
that should not involve flash or a browser plugin, on a server(that is not owned) where we have
php(installed without third party addons), perl and python?

Comment: @Coolboy: There are newer server technologies for running programs in a web server. For Python, the best option at present is called WSGI. See if your hosting provider supports that.

Comment: I know about WSGI(the newest and most versatile python mod). 
What I'm trying to do is to make a plugin that should work on any server
that runs apache, php > 5.2, python > 2.4.3 without any special requirements. Python as cgi
is available almost all the time. If is Apache 2.0.x that has this behaviour then
my plugin requirements will specify apache 2.2.x or higher.

Comment: If is not apache version that cause troubles and
i cannot undo this behaviour by editing some things in .htaccess
(wich also will be required to have access at) i should stop continuing developing this plugin.
But i must first find out if I can correct or trick this server behaviour by myself(somehow) without asking
for any support from hosting provider. I want to target all linux servers(that have those requirements) 
not one server specially.

Plugin requirements example:
apache >= 2.2.x
php >= 5.2
python >= 2.4.3
.htaccess access

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890820/