# I need a super-duper simple CGI Python photo upload

Tags: python, upload, cgi

I've looked through tons of answers but the truth is, I only know super basic python and I really need help. I don't know the os module or anything like that and I can't use PHP (not that I know it anyway, but it's not permitted) and I need something so easy that I can understand it.

Basically, I need a CGI upload (I don't need the HTML form, I've got that much down) that will take the photo and save it. That's it. I don't need any fancy place for it to save, I just need the file to be properly uploaded from the form.

I've got various versions of this function and I can't get them working because I don't understand them so PLEASE HELP!!!

```
import cgi

def savefile (filename, photodoc):
    form=cgi.FieldStorage()
    name=form[filename]
    period=name.split(.)
    if period[1]=="jpeg" or period[1]=="jpg" or period[1]=="png":
        idk what to do
    else:
        make an error message
```

Comment: Show your function(s).

Comment: Maybe instead of asking for answers to be "dumbed down" to your level, try educating yourself up to they're level :)  If you need help understand a programming concept, this site is a great resource for you.  But as it stands now, your question is not a good one and likely won't be answered

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Okay so I guess I don't really want it "dumbed down", but I'm pretty sure there are easier ways. Obviously, I could take the time to educate myself, and I'm working on it, but I'm also under time restraints. The question is how to make a simple CGI upload that will save the photo.

Answer (score 1):

This cgi program will "*take the photo and save it. That's it.*"

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import cgi
field=cgi.FieldStorage()['fieldname']
open(field.filename, 'wb').write(field.value)
```

Among the things it **doesn't** do are error checking and security checking, and specifying in what directory the files should be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question but here's what you need:

Depending if windows or linux, first set to binary mode:

```
try:
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY) 
    msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) 

except ImportError:
    pass
```

Then:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form[filename]
    period = name.split('.') #You need the quotes around the period
    if period[1]=='jpeg' or period[1] == 'jpg' or period[1] =='png':
    if upload.filename:
        name = os.path.basename(upload.filename)
        out = open(YOUR_FILEPATH_HERE + name, 'wb', 1000)
        message = "The file '" + name + "' was uploaded successfully"

        while True:
            packet = upload.file.read(1000)
            if not packet:
                break
            out.write(packet)
        out.close()
    else:
            print 'Error'
```

Some sources:

[How to use Python/CGI for file uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890820/how-to-use-python-cgi-for-file-uploading)
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/273844-minimal-http-upload-cgi/